# Use Remarkable as gem from Github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1, gemfile

i want to use Remarkable gem latest working version, because it has fixed some deprecated features compatibile with Rails 3.1. But when i use

```
gem "remarkable", :git => 'git://github.com/remarkable/remarkable.git'
```

i get this error:

```
Could not find gem 'remarkable (>= 0) ruby' in git://github.com/remarkable/remarkable.git (at master).
Source does not contain any versions of 'remarkable (>= 0) ruby'
```

But dont why. Any hits how to solve this ?

Thanks

EDIT: fixed wrong addres in git address which was in my clippboard when i post this question.

SOLVED!

I created fork with gemspec file, which is necessary to fetch gem from git.

This is working git source

```
gem "remarkable", :git => 'git://github.com/radeno/remarkable.git'
gem "remarkable_activemodel", :git => 'git://github.com/radeno/remarkable.git'
gem "remarkable_activerecord", :git => 'git://github.com/radeno/remarkable.git'
```

or from this fork

https://github.com/foolabs/remarkable/

Answer (score 2):

SOLUTION:

I created fork with gemspec file, which is necessary to fetch gem from git.

This is working git source

```
gem "remarkable", :git => 'git://github.com/radeno/remarkable.git'
gem "remarkable_activemodel", :git => 'git://github.com/radeno/remarkable.git'
gem "remarkable_activerecord", :git => 'git://github.com/radeno/remarkable.git'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use either of these:

```
gem "remarkable", :git => "git://github.com/radeno/remarkable.git"
gem "remarkable", :git => "https://github.com/radeno/remarkable.git"
```

You used a colon instead of a slash.

---

**Edit**:

Could you try and add a specific version?

```
gem "remarkable", "2.3.1", :git => "git://github.com/remarkable/remarkable.git"
```

Comment: My mistake, of course i have it as you written. It was faulty taken from my github account when i post this question. Later I forked it, and create gemspec file. Then it working. But when i require this gem, it respond me, that gem doesnt exists

Comment: No, it doesn't working. But i solve this. There shlould be remarkable_activerecord and remarkable_activemodel with same git source. And of course, git source must have gemspec file! I create fork with this file.

Comment: Solution in first post. Thank you

Comment: Could you put the solution in an answer to your own question and accept it as the solution? You might earn the [Self-Learner Badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/14/self-learner) one day.

Comment: I do, but must wait a little. Not yet enough reputation :)